# Validation of user input to see if it matches member of string array won't validate when they match only recognizes them as different

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why in the if statement it will execute the code for the input being different and say incorrect even when they are the same. I tried checking for the console.log in the console and it's not giving any errors. I know this isn't the case, but it's like it is not recognizing or reading the code.  Sorry for long explanation I'm a beginner and its hard to explain what I'm trying to say.

Here is the code:

```js
let output = document.querySelector("#typedWord");
let ansOutput = document.querySelector('[userOut]');
const display = document.querySelector("#wordDisplay");
const wordList = ['Carvedilol', 'Histrelin', 'Kadcyla', 'Mavyret', 'Paracetamol', 'Raloxifene', 'Saxagliptin'];
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length);

window.addEventListener('keydown', focusIn);

function focusIn(event) {
  const wordList = ['Carvedilol', 'Histrelin', 'Kadcyla', 'Mavyret', 'Paracetamol', 'Raloxifene', 'Saxagliptin'];
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length);
  const ranWord = wordList[random];
  const display = document.querySelector("#wordDisplay");
  let output = document.querySelector("#typedWord");
  if (event.keyCode === 32) {
    display.innerHTML = ranWord;
    setTimeout(time, 6000);
  }
  if (output.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyUp));

  function time(event) {
    const timeDisplay = document.querySelector("#timeDisplay");
    timeDisplay.innerHTML = "Time Up!";
    console.log("time event")
  }

  function handleKeyUp(event) {
    let ansOutput = document.querySelector('[userOut]')
    if (event.keyCode === 13 && ansOutput === ranWord) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.target.blur();
      timeDisplay.innerHTML = "Correct!";
      console.log('executed')
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 13 && ansOutput !== ranWord) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.target.blur();
      timeDisplay.innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
      console.log('executed')
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Type A Word Challenge!</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="wordDisplay"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="timeDisplay"></div>
  <br>
  <label>Type Word Here</label>
  <input type="text" id="typedWord" name="userOut">
  <h3>Press Spacebar to Begin</h3>
</main>
```

Comment: Just console.log() your two compared strings and see what they look like

Comment: Or try document.querySelector('[name="user Out"]', then get its value

Comment: `addEventListener()` doesn't return anything. Why do you have `if` like this: `if (output.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyUp));`. There's also no `if` body.

Comment: You're not getting the value of the input. `let ansOutput = document.querySelector('[userOut]')` should be `let ansOutput = document.querySelector('[userOut]').value`

Comment: Why do you repeat all the `let` bindings in the functions that you already have as global variables?

Comment: When I put .value on the end of document.querySelector('[userOut]') the console gives me an error that says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') at HTMLInputElement.handleKeyUp    I tried .value many times and this is the problem I keep running into. The reason I repeated all the let bindings is because I couldn't figure out what the problem was, and I was trying different things. I appreciate the help if you have any more thoughts, please let me know.

Comment: It is null because your css selector is incorrect. The element has no attribute 'userOut'. There is a 'name' attribute and its value is 'userOut', so use `document.querySelector('[name="userOut"]').value` or better `document.querySelector("#typedWord").value`.